# What are the principal Saiva Tantras?

Tags: tantra, shaivism, agamas, kashmiri-shaivism, trika

Saiva Agamaic literature has two divisions. One is Saiva Agamas. These are dualistic in nature. Mostly prevalent in Tamilnadu. Based on it Saiva Siddhanta Darshana was formed. However, apart from Saiva Agamas, there are Saiva Tantras as well. These are distinct from 64 Shakta Tantras. These Saiva Tantras are monoistic in nature. Kashmiri Saivism is based on these Tantras. Abhinavagupta wrote his magnum opus Tantraloka, where he mentioned the 64 Saiva Tantras. Where can I find the list of 64 Saiva Tantras? Please mention the 64 Saiva Tantra with an authentic source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NINETY TWO SAIVA TANTRAS AND AGAMAS

### TANTRAS

(A) EIGHTFOLD CLASSIFICATION OF THE SIXTYFOUR BHAIRAVA TANTRAS

I. Bhairavāştaka

1. Svacchanda, 2. Canda, 3. Bhairava, 4. Krodha, 5. Unmattabhairava, 6. Asitānga, 7. Mahocchuşma, 8. Kapālīśa

II. Yamalāştaka

1. Brahmayāmala, 2. Visnuyāmala, 3. Svacchanda, 4. Ruru, 5. Ātharvana, 6. Rudra, 7. Vetāla, 8. **

III. Matākhyāstaka

1. Rakta, 2. Lampata, 3. Mata, 4. Lakşmi, 5. Calikā, 6. Pingalā, 7. Utphullaka, 8. Viśvādya

IV. Mangalāstaka

1. Picubhairavi, 2. Tantrabhairavi, 3. Tatabhairavi, 4. Brāhmikalā, 5. Vijayā, 6. Candrākhyā, 7. Mangala, 8. Sarvamangalā

V. Cakrāstaka

1. Mantracakra, 2. Varnacakrn, 3. Sakticakra, 4. Kalacakra, 5. Vinducakra, 6. Nādacakra, 7. Guhyacakra, 8. Khacakra

VI. Bahurūpāstaka

1. Andhaka, 2. Rurubheda, 3. Aja, 4. Mūla, 5. Varnabhantha, 6. Vidanga, 7. Javālin, 8. Mātrrodana

VII. Vāgiśāstaka

1. Bhairavi, 2. Citrikā, 3. Hamsa, 4. Kadambikā, 5. Hrllekā, 6. Candralekhā, 7. Vidullekhā, 8. Vidumat

VIII. Śikhāstaka

1. Bhairavaviśākhā, 2. Vinā, 3. Viņāmaņi, 4. Sammoha, 5. Dāmara, 6. Atharvaka, 7. Kabandha, 8. Siraścheda

- This list is based on the description provided by Jayaratha in his commentary Viveka [TA I.18].

(B) Vāmakeśvara Tantra or Nityāsodasikārņava Tantra
(I. 13-20) enumerates the following sixty-four tantra:

1.Mahāmayāśambara or Mahāmāyā Tantra, 2. Yoginijālasambara or Jālasambaratantra, 3-10. Bhairavāstaka (8), 11-18. Bahurupastaka (8), 19-26. Yāmālistaka (8), 27. Candrajñāna, 28. Vāsuki, 29. Mahāsammohana, 30. Mahocchuşma, 31. Mahadeva, 32. Vātula, 33. Vātulottara, 34. Hrdbheda, 35. Mātrbheda, 36. Guhya, 37. Kāmika, 38. Kalāvāda, 39. Kalāsāra, 40. Kubjikā, 41. Matottara, 42. Vāņā, 43. Trotala, 44. Trotalottar, 45-49. Pañcāmrta, 50. Rūpabheda, 51. Bhuta, 52. Dāmara, 53. Kulasārā, 54. Sarvajñānottara, 55. Mahākāli, 56. Mahālakṣmi, 57. Siddhayogiśvari, 58. Kurūpikā, 59. Rūpikāmata, 60. Sarvavira, 61. Vimala, 62. Aruneśa, 63. Mohiniśa, 64. Visuddheśvara

### AGAMAS

(C) TEN DUALIST TANTRA (or Saivagamas)

According to the details provided by Räjänaka Jayaratha:

1. Kāmika, 2. Yogaja, 3. Cintya, 4. Mukuta, 5. Anśmān 6. Dīpta, 7. Ajita, 8. Sūksma, 9. Sahasra, 10. Sūprabheda.

According to Kiranāgama:

1. Kāmika, 2. Yogaja, 3. Cintya, 4. Kāraņa, 5. Ajita, 6. Dīpta, 7. Sūkşma, 8. Sahastra, 9. Sūprabheda, 10. Anśumat.

(D) EIGHTEEN DUALIST-CUM-NON-DUALIST TANTRA (or Rudragamas)

1. Vijaya, 2. Niḥśvāsa, 3. Madagīta (in some places it is prodgīta), 4. Pārameśvara, 5. Mukhabimba, 6. Siddha, 7. Santāna, 8. Nāsimha, 9. Candrānśu, 10. Vīrabbadra, 11. Āgneya, 12. Śambhū, 13. Visara, 14. Raurava, 15. Vimala, 16. Kirana, 17. Lalita, 18. Saumeya.

Kiraṇāgama enumerates as follows:

1. Vijaya, 2. Parameśa, 3. Nihśvāsa, 4. Prodgita, 4. Mukhabimba, 5. Siddhamata, 6. Santāna, 7. Nārasimha, 8. Candrahāsa, 9. Bhadra, 10. Svāyambhuva, 11. Virakta, 12. Kauravya, 13. Mukuta, 14. Kirana, 15. Lalita, 16. Āgneya, 17. Para

Comment: Credit goes to kashmir shaivism group in telegram.

Comment: Wonderful. Do you have any link to Jayaratha's commentary Viveka?

Comment: Does TA mean Tantraloka?

Comment: Do you know which verse of Tantraloka talks about the number of tantras?

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay tantraloka directly doesnt talk about all the tantras' list but shree jayaratha in his commentary does. In the first chapter, 18th verse. About the link, last i saw it was there on archive, hindi translated. But message me on telegram if you don't find it there.  Rudra_118